# No trigger by the name "interval" was found

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, apscheduler

I've been working with APScheduler and when attempting to run the code I get the error "No trigger by the name 'interval' was found"

It was perfectly on my local machine but will work on my cloud machine.

I have tried: reinstalling apscheduler via pip, easy_install, and manually; upgrading setuptools; upgrading all dependencies.

Edit: Code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(SMS, 'interval', minutes=1)
    scheduler.start()
    print Run Complete

    try:
        # This is here to simulate application activity (which keeps the main thread alive).
        while True:
            time.sleep(2)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        scheduler.shutdown()  # Not strictly necessary if daemonic mode is enabled but should be done if possible


LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-2895cd586d3f> in <module>()
      1 if __name__ == '__main__':
      2     scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
----> 3     scheduler.add_job(SMS, 'interval', hours=1)
      4     scheduler.start()
      5     print "Run Complete"

/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/base.pyc in add_job(self, func, trigger, args, kwargs, id, name, misfire_grace_time, coalesce, max_instances, next_run_time, jobstore, executor, replace_existing, **trigger_args)
    328 
    329         job_kwargs = {
--> 330             'trigger': self._create_trigger(trigger, trigger_args),
    331             'executor': executor,
    332             'func': func,

/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/base.pyc in _create_trigger(self, trigger, trigger_args)
    780 
    781         # Instantiate the trigger class
--> 782         return self._create_plugin_instance('trigger', trigger, trigger_args)
    783 
    784     def _create_lock(self):

/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/base.pyc in _create_plugin_instance(self, type_, alias, constructor_kwargs)
    764                     raise TypeError('The {0} entry point does not point to a {0} class'.format(type_))
    765             else:
--> 766                 raise LookupError('No {0} by the name "{1}" was found'.format(type_, alias))
    767 
    768         return plugin_cls(**constructor_kwargs)

LookupError: No trigger by the name "interval" was found
```

Comment: Please show the calling code that gives this error or we can't help you.

Comment: Uhh, try again. For one, I can't even read that, as I'm sure many others can't. For another, by site rules you are not supposed to post pictures of code. Please find a way to include the code in your question.

Comment: Well, have you created a trigger called `'interval'` on the cloud machine?

Comment: Peter - it should be included in the apscheduler library (as it is every time I run it on local)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was working in ipython on a different server. I tried uninstalling/upgrading setuptools and APScheduler. Then I copy and pasted the exact same code I already had into a new notebook that I created on the second server.

And it worked.

Answer (score 5):

This issue is caused by an old version of setuptools.  See https://bitbucket.org/agronholm/apscheduler/issues/77/lookuperror-no-trigger-by-the-name

You can solve this by running `sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools` and reinstallation of apscheduler with `sudo pip install --ignore-installed apscheduler`

Answer (score 3):

The other answers point to environmental causes, but it might also be how you're using APScheudler.

- If using PyInstaller, see this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51124464/pyinstaller-3-3-1-3-4-0-dev-build-with-apscheduler)

Otherwise, verify that the APScheduler class (scheduler/trigger/jobstore/job) is instantiated correctly

- If this is the case, the `LookupError` is likely thrown by the `BaseScheduler` as it tries to access the scheduler's triggers, jobstores, and executors. As of version 3.6.3, that's in the `_create_plugin_instance()` method of [base.py](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/blob/master/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py)

It'd also be good to verify that your file doesn't use the same name as the APScheduler library

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the problem with the frozen environment by `PyInstaller` and `cx_Freeze`, and `Flask`, although there is no problem with the virtual one. My configuration and the code as follow,

```
Python 3.6.7 64bit
APScheduler          3.5.3
Flask-APScheduler    1.11.0
Flask                1.0.2
dash                 0.32.2
cx-Freeze            5.1.1
PyInstaller          3.4

# The code produces the error
scheduler = APScheduler()
@scheduler.task('interval', id='do_job_1', seconds=30, misfire_grace_time=900)
def job1():
print('Job 1 executed')
```

After the code fixed as follow, the problem disappeared,

```
from apscheduler.triggers.interval import IntervalTrigger
scheduler = APScheduler()
@scheduler.task(IntervalTrigger(seconds=30), id='do_job_1', misfire_grace_time=900)
def job1():
    server.logger.info('Job 1 executed')
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem.

My code **NOT** working:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

def job1():
    print("Job 1 fired")


scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(job1, 'interval', seconds=2, id="job1")
scheduler.start()
```

This is how I fixed it:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.interval import IntervalTrigger

def job1():
    print("Job 1 fired")

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(job1, IntervalTrigger(), seconds=2, id="job1")
scheduler.start()
```

I have no idea about what was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you use virtualenv 1.11.6 as I do, upgrade it to 12.0.7 should fix this problem. according to this thread https://bitbucket.org/agronholm/apscheduler/issue/77/lookuperror-no-trigger-by-the-name you may need to upgrade your setuptools too.