# Schedule error in Python

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I am extracting info from XYZ website and save it to sqlite. I want this process repeat every 15 minutes. So my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import urllib
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from collections import OrderedDict
import sqlite3
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

def get_data():
    query = ("WEBSITE_ADDRESSCOM/XYZ.json")
    raw_data = pd.read_json(query)
    conn = sqlite3.connect('X.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    disk_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///X.db')
    raw_data.to_sql('table', disk_engine, if_exists='append')
    print("I downloaded", pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM 
    table',disk_engine).shape[0],"cases")
    conn.close()

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(get_data, 'interval', minutes=15)
scheduler.start()
```

But it gives me this error.

LookupError: No trigger by the name "interval" was found

This code works on Windows. I am trying on Mac now (with Python 3) but it gives above error although I followed recommendations on this link
[No trigger by the name "interval" was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682723/no-trigger-by-the-name-interval-was-found).

Comment: So... what line did this error occur on?

Comment: I think  scheduler.add_job(get_data, 'interval', minutes=15)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did and it worked on Mac too.

I updated setuptools as outlined here: [No trigger by the name "interval" was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682723/no-trigger-by-the-name-interval-was-found)

Then I run below code.

```
sudo -H pip  install --ignore-installed apscheduler
```

I am not sure if that is relevant but I restarted the kernel after this procedure and now it works.