# Pyinstaller with APScheduler - TypeError with IntervalTrigger

Tags: python, pyinstaller, apscheduler

I had the same problem as here (see link below), brielfy: unable to create .exe of a python script that uses APScheduler

[Pyinstaller 3.3.1 & 3.4.0-dev build with apscheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51124464/pyinstaller-3-3-1-3-4-0-dev-build-with-apscheduler)

So I did as suggested:

```
from apscheduler.triggers import interval
    
scheduler.add_job(Run, 'interval', interval.IntervalTrigger(minutes = time_int), 
                                  args = (input_file, output_dir, time_int), 
                                  id = theID, replace_existing=True)
```

And indeed importing interval.IntervalTrigger and passing it as an argument to add_job solved *this* particular error.

However, now I am encountring:

> TypeError: add_job() got multiple values for argument 'args'

I tested it and I can ascertain it is occurring because of the way trigger is called now. I also tried defining trigger = interval.IntervalTrigger(minutes = time_int) separately and then just passing trigger, and the same happens.

If I ignore the error with try/except, I see that it does not add the job to the sql database at all (I am using SQLAlchemy as a jobstore). Initially I thought it is because I am adding several jobs in a for loop, but it happens with a single job add as well.

Anyone know of some other workaround if the initial problem, or any idea why this error might occur? I can't find anything online either :(

Answer (score 0):

Things always work better in the morning.

For anyone else who encounters this: you don't need both 'interval' and interval.IntervalTrigger() as arguments, the code should be, this is where the error comes from.

```
scheduler.add_job(Run, interval.IntervalTrigger(minutes = time_int), 
                          args = (input_file, output_dir, time_int), 
                          id = theID, replace_existing=True)
```