# Apscheduler has no triggers listed

Tags: python, apscheduler, entry-point

I am currently trying to setup a scheduler (using `apscheduler`), and it fails when adding a job:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

def job():
    print('hello world')

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(func=job, trigger='interval', seconds=5)
```

Which results in a `LookupError: No trigger by the name "interval" was found` error.

I have tried to find the triggers for the scheduler, but `BlockingScheduler._trigger_plugins` and `iter_entry_points('apscheduler.triggers')` are both empty.

This doesn't happen on each of my tests, but just on one and I am trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a new issue, take a look at the [original issue](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/issues/77) and this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682723/no-trigger-by-the-name-interval-was-found). Reinstalling `setuptools` and `apscheduler` should help:

```
pip uninstall -y setuptools apscheduler
pip install -U setuptools apscheduler
```

Comment: Thank you for the links. I tried your solution and the ones in the second thread, but it doesn't prevent the error.