# How to import APScheduler?

Tags: python-3.x, apscheduler

Reading the answer in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/53938833/4187237, I don't get how to import the class

```
   APScheduler()
```

Does enyone have any idea on how to do it? I'm looking for somthing like

```
   from apscheduler import APScheduler
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of `APScheduler` as a scheduler type, you can see the list of valid schedulers in the [documentation](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide.html#choosing-the-right-scheduler-job-store-s-executor-s-and-trigger-s). That answer is a few years old and using [APScheduler 3.5.3](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5.3/) whereas the latest stable version is 3.6.3.

Using a `BlockingScheduler` as an example, you can achieve the desired effect:

```py
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()

@scheduler.scheduled_job('interval', id="my_job_id", seconds=5)
def test():
    print("Working")

scheduler.start()
```

Comment: You are right, the user in the question I was mantioning just invented (don't know why) the class APScheduler and I was really confused by that.